# find unique value from python list

Tags: python

How do I find unique items for a list of lists?

In the following example I expect only 2 items.

```
mylist=[[' Dish Towel .\n', '1.000', '149.000'],
 [' Dish Towel .\n', '1.000', '149.000'],
 [' Kitchentowel(mix designs) .\n', '1.000', '99.000'],
 [' Kitchentowel(mix designs) .\n', '1.000', '99.000']]
```

Expected result:

```
newlist=[[' Dish Towel .\n', '1.000', '149.000'],
 [' Kitchentowel(mix designs) .\n', '1.000', '99.000']]
```

I tried this but I got TypeError.

```
  output = set()
  for x in mylist:
       output.add(x)
  print output
```

Comment: `output.add(tuple(x))`? Lists are mutable and cannot be stored in sets.

Comment: Slightly off-topic: Those inner lists look to me like they would be better modeled with dictionaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
output = []
for x in mylist:
    if x not in output:
        output.append(x)
print output
```

Comment: This works, but runs in worst-case O(n^2) time, so it may not be preferable for especially large lists.

Comment: worst-case should only be O(n) because there is only one loop.

Comment: O(n) for the loop, and O(n) for the `in` operation, combines to form O(n^2)

Comment: Your right I forgot about that. I thought that this may be useful because it would keep the output in the same format as the input instead of a set of tuples but your are right it may be a little slow.

Comment: Yes, keeping the original typing is possibly an advantage. As well as maintaining the original ordering of the items, which may or may not be important to the OP.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `set` to preserve the unique items :

```
>>> set(map(tuple,mylist))
set([(' Kitchentowel(mix designs) .\n', '1.000', '99.000'), (' Dish Towel .\n', '1.000', '149.000')])
```

Note that since `set` just accept hashable objects you need to covert the lists to tuple then use `set`