# Creating list of only non redundant elements in a preexisting list

Tags: python

I want to create a list with elements appearing only once.
Here's what I've tried.

```
years_of_birth = years_of_birth = [1990, 1991, 1990, 1990, 1992, 1991]

ages = []

for year in years_of_birth:
    ages.append(2022 - year)

print(ages)

unique_ages = []

for age in ages:
    if operator.countOf(1, age):
        print(unique_ages)
```

Comment: First search result: [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists) – 1372 upvotes and 58 answers.

Comment: Or: [find unique value from python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171410/find-unique-value-from-python-list)

Comment: I want to print a new list with only the unique elements of the previous one, is that not obvious from the code itself where i define "unique_ages = []" @wovano

Comment: In that case your question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171410/find-unique-value-from-python-list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find unique value from python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171410/find-unique-value-from-python-list)

Answer (score 0):

`operator.countOf(a, b)` is used for counting the number of occurrences of `b` in `a`. So if you want a boolean you have to add a comparison like:

```
if operator.countOf(years_of_birth, 1990) == 1:
```

But it's easier to just use `set` since it removes duplicates:

```
list(set(ages))
```

Comment: Using `set` is incorrect since it does not only return the unique elements, which is the question.

Comment: @movano not sure what you mean. Have you tried `print(set([1,2,2,3,1]))` in python? You get `{1,2,3}`

Comment: Exactly, you get `{1, 2, 3}`, but 2 is not unique in the list, since it occurs twice. It's not completely clear what the OP wants, but your two methods provide different results.